# SSIS connection to Informix does not save password

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, informix

I'm using SSIS 2012 to connect to an Informix database (Avaya CMS) via n ADO NET connection.
I've set the debugging run64bit to false in the project properties. so it should use the 32bit informix openlink drivers.

We've got an OpenLink ODBC connection set up that works with Access and that I'm able to create the connection manager in SSIS with. When I enter the password in the connection manager and test the connection it's fine.

I go to create an ADO net datasource and I get prompted to input the password. Fine I do and I can see the tables from CMS and choose one as a data source.

When I go to preview it I get errors: A whole lot of

```
ERROR [HY010] [OpenLink][ODBC][Driver]Function sequence error
```

followed at the end by

```
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.NextResult(Boolean disposing, Boolean allresults)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.Close(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.Close()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.ReinitializeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostReinitializeMetaData(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this and how can I get around it?

Thanks

Comment: What is your project and/or package protection level? While I generally advocate DontSaveSensitive, this is one of the areas where it's a pain in the backside so I will usually develop packages with EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey so the password is retained and when I'm ready to deploy, then I use an SSIS Environment setting to apply the password

Comment: I'm currently set for DontSaveSensitive. I'll try EncryptSensitivewithUserKey and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Suspect it will. SSIS attempts to prevent the storage of sensitive data (user name and password) in clear text. DontSaveSensitive blanks out the values in user and password fields when you save. Pre-project deployment model, I got around this challenge by using Configuration and having it set the user and pass but haven't had to find a resolution in the project deployment model

Comment: Making that change had no effect. I get the same errors.

Comment: Well, now you have my curiosity. Is there something specific about the table itself? What are the data types in that table? What if you write a `SELECT * FROM 'mytable'` instead of selecting it in the drop down, does that work? I don't have access to an Informix database any more so I can't repro your situation. If the SELECT * fails, try selecting just one column, preferably something that isn't LOB or "funky"

Comment: What I get now is an invalid username/password error message.

Comment: I just stumbled across this question. There are a few ways to handle this issue, if it persists, either on the SSIS host or on the CMS/Informix host. I suggest you bring such questions about OpenLink components to the public [OpenLink Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com) or a confidential [Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).